# Safe mounting of decorative hook with small holes

Tags: drywall, screws, hanging, anchor

I have a few of these hooks I'd like to mount, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to secure them. I determined the holes are a bit wider than 7/64 inches by passing that size drill bit through them. I've been looking for screws and anchors that size but I'm not quite sure whether they would even be secure enough? Not looking to put a tonne of weight on this but still would like it to stay put.

I guess I don't necessarily need an anchor if I find a stud to screw them into?

[image: picture of hook]

Edit: mounting on a wall with a layer of drywall and then plaster underneath. Will be used for hanging clothes / towels, nothing too heavy.

Comment: Just drill out the holes in the hook to accommodate whatever screw size is proper for the anchor you need. NOTE: it would help if you edit your question so that it includes a description of what type of surface you will mount to and what the hook is intended to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit wider than 7/64" (0.109375") is likely suited for a #4 (0.112") wood (or sheetmetal) screw. #3 (0.99") will definitely fit.

Or just take the hook to the hardware store with you to be sure of screw size.

Note that most of the force on such a hook will be down, not out - or shear, not tension.

Comment: Part of the problem for me is understanding the terminology. So looking at [this](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/paulin--4-22-x-5-8-inch-steel-pan-head-square-drive-tapping-screw-type-a-zinc-plated-23-pcs-/1000114399) it says #4-22 x 5/8 inch — so is that 5/8 inches long, and #4 indicates the diameter? What's the 22? (Also normally would just go to a store but trying to minimize indoor trips right now, so buying online is a bit trickier.) EDIT: ok so I'm seeing that the 22 refers to the number of threads per inch

Comment: Do anchors follow the same numbering? And if the wall is plaster does that mean there's a special kind of anchor I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that the manufacturer probably intended this as a coat/robe/towel/purse hook and considered that 2 screws of the size that will fit through those holes, when installed into a stud or proper wall anchor, would be sufficient to hold the expected weight.

i.e. find screws that will fit the holes and attach it to the wall without too much over thinking.